# How can I speed up my Perl regex matching?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to capture several text using the following regex:

```
$text_normal = qr{^(\/F\d+) FF (.*?) SCF SF (.*?) MV (\(.*?)SH$};
```

A sample of the string is like below:

```
my $text = '/F12345 FF FF this is SCF SF really MV (important stuff SH';
```

Can that be rewritten to speed up the matching?

Comment: No need to escape `/` given that this is in a `qr{}`.

Comment: Are you sure that's the slow part of your program?

Answer (score 22):

There's no single answer to optimizing a regex. You can watch what a particular regex is doing with the [re](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html) pragma:

```
 use re 'debugcolor';
```

Once you see what it traverses the string, you see where it is having problems and adjust your regex from there. You'll learn a little about the regex engine as you do that.

You should also check out [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570), which tells you how regular expressions work and why some patterns are slower than others.

Answer (score 7):

Without seeing some sample data it is hard to say.

Generally, it is a good idea to avoid using `.*`.  Look for any possible sources of unneeded backtracking, and eliminate them.

You might be able to get away with a `split` with a slice if your needs are simple.

```
 my @vals = (split / /, $string)[0,2,5,7];
```

Answer (score 6):

This very much depends on the profile of the data you are scanning.

You identify the piece of your regular expression which filters out the most input and do a separate simpler regular expression for that expression.

For instance, if only 5% of your input date contained the `'MV'` string, you could filter for this first and only apply the full more complex regular expression if the simpler one is true.

So you would have:

```
if ( $text_normal =~ / MV / ) {
  $text_normal = qr{^(\/F\d+) FF (.*?) SCF SF (.*?) MV (\(.*?)SH$};
  if .......
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're just checking for a static string in your first pass to weed things out, consider benchmarking whether `index(' MV ')` is faster than doing a regex match for it.

Answer (score 3):

`(.*)` means that you are dealing with any number of repetitions of " SCF SF " before you find the one that indicates it's the next capture. By making it non-greedy, you're still handling the capability that even 'SCF SF' would appear in the capture after 'FF'. I think you are handling a lot of cases you don't need.

The best way to optimize a regular expression sometimes makes it more cryptic--but you definitely find ways to make the expression *fail earlier*. `(.*?)` while not being "greedy" is definitely *too* tolerant.

Below is a more verbose, but faster failing alternative to your second capture.

```
((?:[^S]|S[^C]|SC[^F]|SCF[^ ]|SCF [^S]|SCF S[^F])*)
```

But you can optimize it even more if you think that the string `\bSCF\b` should automatically make the capture commit and expect only "\bSCF SF\b". Thus you could re-write that as:

```
((?:[^S]|S[^C]|SC[^F]SCF\B)*) SCF SF
```

But you can optimize these strings even more by backtracking control. If you think that there is no way in the world that SCF would ever occur as a word and not be followed by SF on valid input. To do that, you add another group around it, with brackets `(?>` and `)`.

```
(?>((?:[^S]|S[^C]|SC[^F]SCF\B)*)) SCF SF
```

That means that the matching logic will in no way try to reassess what it captured. If the characters after this fail to be " SCF SF " the whole expression fails. And it fails long before it ever gets to try to accommodate "MV" and other sub-expressions.

In fact, given certain expressions about the uniqueness of the delimiters, the fastest performance for this expression would be:

```
$text_normal = qr{^(\/F\d+) FF (?>((?:[^S]|S[^C]|SC[^F]SCF\B)*))SCF SF (?>((?:[^M]|M[^V]|MV\B)*))MV (?>(\((?:[^S]|S[^H]|SH.)*))SH$};
```

Additionally, the verbose, exhaustive negative matches can be alternative expressed by negative lookaheads--but I have no idea on how that works on performance. But negative lookaheads would work like this:

```
((?:.(?! SCF))*) SCF SF
```

This means that for this capture I want any character that is not a space starting the string " SCF SF ".

Answer (score 1):

Backtracking is one of the surest ways to kill regex performance, but, unfortunately, this does not appear to be a case where you're able to completely eliminate the `.` wildcard in favor of character classes, unless the text you're capturing is prohibited from containing uppercase characters.  (If that prohibition does exist, you could replace your `.*?` with, say, `[a-z ]*` instead.)

You can still reduce the possibility for backtracking by using `{}` to set a minimum/maximum number of characters to match, such as `.{0,10}?` if the match can't be longer than 10 characters.